# Npm run dev doesnt start up nuxt 3 local server

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

My Nuxt app was initially built with Nuxt2, but recently I had some errors with ESlint and I was forced to upgrade and migrate the application to Nuxt3.
However on migrating, the application local server doesn't startup with the startup script. Below is an image showing the output when running `npm run dev`

[image]

Nodejs : 18^
nuxtjs: 3^
vuejs: 2.7^

Answer (score 1):

Nuxt3 is using Vue3, not Vue2.7.
Also, your app is fine when you run `npm run dev` so you don't need to run `npm nuxi dev` per-se.

You could run `npx nuxi-edge@latest dev` as [suggested here](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/edge-channel#using-latest-nuxi-cli-from-edge).
That one works thanks to `npx` not `npm`, which is quite different. `npx` doesn't need you to have the package installed locally or globally on the system, it can fetch the whole code remotely and run it on the fly straight away.

Still, in your case: use `npm run dev`, it's all good that way.
No need to run it through npx/nuxi, that just adds delay.

Comment: Thanks somuch for the answer @kissu, well for this my case, i have resolved the issue and it was all a nodejs upgrade problem.

Comment: @RomanricAkam mind giving more details?

Comment: Well the initial problem started with the eslint conflicts which came as a result of the difference in node versions, nit knowing this, i when ahead and upgraded my nuxt version to 3 thinking it will fix the error, but it instead made it worst, later showing an error about a hash function in my node_modules that wasnt supported in nodejs, its from that error that i knew it was because of the nodejs upgrade i had done, imidiately i downgraded my nodejs back to v16, everything was fine again.

Comment: @RomanricAkam bump a Nuxt version (which is quite a big deal) to fix an ESlint issue is indeed probably not the way to go. Also, Nuxt2 works well with Node v16 while Nuxt3 works well with Node v18. At the end, what fixed your issue and is it working now?

Comment: In the `package.json` you check to see `nuxt` (and optionally `vue`) is v2